# log all handled exception using log4net + AutoFac interceptor

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, log4net, autofac

I'm using `Log4Net`to log my application. currently I want to log every methods enter in my app (for testing purpose). Therefor I'm using `AutoFac` interception capabilities, somethong like this:

```
builder.Register(c=> new MyClass()).As<IMyInterface>().EnableInterfaceInterceptors().InterceptedBy(typeof(LoggerClass));

builder.Build();
```

and my `LoggerClass` looks something like this:

```
public class LoggerClass : StandartInterceptor
{
    ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LoggerClass));

    override void PreProceed(IInvocation invovation)
    {
         _log.Info(string.Format("entering method: {0}",invocation.Method.Name);
    }
}
```

for now this implementation will print message for all method invocation (the interceptor catches all methods entries).

**Question**

I would like to use this interception mechanism to log every **handled** Exception.
For example instead of coding this:

```
catch (myException ex)
{
     _log.Error(string.Format("catches exception {0}", ex.Message));
}
```

I'll have extra method in my `LoggerClass` that will wrap the catch statement and inject to it log message.
Is there any way to do it using `Log4Net`? since basically the interceptor work around the method, and I need it to work inside method.

Answer (score 0):

On your caught exceptions, you will never enter into the `catch` block of your interceptor.

Therefore, in your method when you catch an exception, you can handle the caught exception in an additional intercepted method that will get logged appropriately.  This will inflate your codebase a bit, but you will end up getting the information you want without sacrificing your architecture.

```
public void InterceptedMethod()
{
  try
  {
    //Some code that fails.
  }
  catch
  {
     HandleException();
  }
}

//Intercept this method also
public void HandleException()
{

}
```

Comment: ,10x for your answer. but I have some problem with it. The reason I'm using interceptor is because its allows me to configure logging policy from one place (my LoggerClass),so after my app will get stable I'll be able to change my policy from one place. And if, for example, I want to to turn off my logging every catch call I will be able to that from one place , instead of cleaning all calling in catch statement.